# Http doPost() does not work

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying a simple login servlet with http doPost().

The Login.html is:

```
<form action="P3" method="post">
Username :- 
<input type="text" name="usnm"><p>
Password :- 
<input type="password" name="pswd"><p>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

My servlet code is: Server.java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException
{
    try
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String un=req.getParameter("usnm");
        String pw=req.getParameter("pswd");

        if(un.equals("abc") && pw.equals("123"))
            res.sendRedirect("welcome.html");
        else
            res.sendRedirect("nologin.html");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If login is successful then welcome.html is to be shown or else nologin.html.

I added this to my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>z</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Server</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>z</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/P3</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I try to execute the Login.html after 'Login' click, I get error:
*can't find the file at /C:/Users/OWNER/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/vaishnavee/P3.*

Please suggest some solution to make this work.

Comment: WHICH file is not found? you know you used the right user/pass, which means welcome.html isn't there? or you failed login, and nologin.html isn't there?

Comment: You Server.class is realy not in a package?

Comment: @Marc B Both welcome.html and nologin.html are in the same location as of Login.html. The error says can't find the file at /C:/Users/OWNER/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/vaishnavee/P3

Comment: My suggestion would really be not to deal with all of this by hand. Use Spring Boot and Spring Security, then focus on getting your interesting work done.

Comment: @chrylis I am a new user in servlets and I wanted to start from basics. The code looks simple enough but I'm not getting the error point.

Comment: How do you access login.html? Which URL? At which folder are the html files?

Comment: @Tobías I am keeping all the html files in folder vaishnavee along with WEB-INF. and I directly run the Login.html in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably displaying the form directly from your hard disk, rather than the tomcat server. You can probably see this in the address field of your browser: `file://C:/Users/OWNER/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/vaishnavee/Login.html` instead of `http://..../Login.html`.

The action of the form is relative to the place where the form itself came from. So if the form itself came directly from drive `C:` instead of tomcat, then the browser will calculate the full URL of the action based on the same URL you see in your address field, but with `Login.html` replaced with `P3`. Of course, you don't have a file by that name so the form cannot be passed to it.

You should either:

1. Display the form from the web server (Could be `http://localhost/Login.html` but you have to use whatever URL was configured for your server)
2. Change the action of the form to the full server address including `P3`.

The first way is the preferred way, as serving the form directly from your `C:` drive is not going to work when you deploy the application or hand it out.

Comment: Yes,that solved the problem.I changed the URL to that of server n it worked smoothly.Thank you!